# Clone new object of old object without old reference in C#

Tags: c#, object

I have a huge object with a lot of attributes and child objects. Because of a poorly designed database which I can't control, I need to find matching objects in `allCourses` with the attribute `CourseType = "SVYE"`. For those who matches the condition, I want to change all values from `"SVYE"` to `"SVYR"` instead and add them to the original object `allCourses`.

I realized that when you declare `svCourse` you still have the old references in courses which will cause all objects with the value on `CourseType = "SVYR"`. Instead of every match should be one with `CourseType = "SVYE"` and one with `CourseType = "SVYR"`.

How could I create a copy of the matching values without having the **reference** to `allCourses` in the new var `svCourses` without declaring every attribute again?

```
new Course(){

name = a.name
// etc..
}
```

**My code:**

```
  var svCourses = allCourses.Where(x => x.Occasions
                  .Any(y => y.CourseType.Equals("SVYE")))
                  .ToList();

         
            foreach(var svCourse in svCourses)
            {
                foreach(var o in svCourse.Occasions)
                {
                    o.CourseType = "SVYR";
                }
                allCourses.Add(svCourse);
            }

           

            return allCourses;
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand for me, what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you could create minimal reproducible example that would be really helpful.

Comment: `allCourses.Add(svCourse);` inside foreach loop, you are updating one property of a reference object and that is why it is updating actual object's property as well as referenced object property

Comment: if you mean each course should have a list of Occasions , one with type "svyr" and one "svye", then i believe the solution for your problem is to do a linq query over allCourses and delete Occasions with CourseType.Equals("SVYE"). Then Do a foreach loop again over allCourses and add to the list of Occasions , the CourseType s you want. Note: if this solves your problem please tell to add the code as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to keep Courses that have Occasions with CourseType.Equals("SVYE") unchanged in your collection and add a copy of that courses with modified only CourseType (CourseType = "SVYR"). Right?

If so, you must somehow **deep-clone** the svCourses collection with 3-rd party library:

[Json.NET NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/):

```
var svCourses = allCourses.Select(x => new 
                {
                  Course = x, 
                  MatchedOccasions = x.Occasions
                                      .Where(y => string.Equals(y.CourseType, "SVYE"))
                                      .ToArray()
                })
                .Where(x => x.MatchedOccasions.Length > 0)
                .ToList();

var clonedSvCourses = JArray.FromObject(svCourses.Select(x => x.Course).ToList()).ToObject<List<Course>>();

allCourses.AddRange(clonedSvCourses);

foreach(var occasion in svCourses.SelectMany(x => x.MatchedOccasions))
{
   occasion.CourseType = "SVYR";
}

return allCourses;
```

[FastDeepCloner NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastDeepCloner/) I think, can be used too.

Comment: You understand me correctly! I tried your solution but I get this error message: "object serialized to array. jobject instance expected"

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution on my own!

I used a **third-party** library called [CloneExtensions](https://github.com/MarcinJuraszek/CloneExtensions). This library could be used to create a **deep copy** of your object without declaring every attribute. This new variable `newCourses` which is a **deep copy** of `svCourses` doesn't have the old reference to `allCourses`, which solves the problem.

This solution will replace `o.CourseType = "SVYR";` for **all ocassions** in the variable `newCourses`.

```
  var svCourses = allCourses.Where(x => x.Occasions
      .Any(y => y.CourseType.Equals("SVYE")))
      .ToList();

  var newCourses = svCourses.Select(x => 
      CloneExtensions.CloneFactory.GetClone(x));
        
     
        foreach(var svCourse in newCourses)
        {
            foreach(var o in svCourse.Occasions)
            {
                o.CourseType = "SVYR";
            }
            allCourses.Add(svCourse);
        }

       

        return allCourses;
```

Comment: You replace to "SVYR" all the occasions, not only "SVYE", is that intended?

Comment: Nope, this solution will just add for every match on "SVYE" one extra object with CourseType = "SVYR". The old object with "SVYE" will still exist in the original list allCourses.

Comment: I mean can you have a situation when the course contains two occasions, for example:
{
  occasions: [
  {courseType: "SVYE"}, {courseType: "XXXX"}]
}

Comment: Yes, but all the occasions on that course should have SVYR then so it's fine. Thanks for that feedback.

Comment: In that case you update the clone of that course and get something like:
 { occasions: [ {courseType: "SVYR"}, {courseType: "SVYR"}] }

Answer (score 0):

Any means `Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.`

What you need is

1. List all occasions of all courses.
2. Choose occasions that `CourseType = SVYE`

```
var svCourses = allCourses
    .SelectMany(c => c.Occasions)
    .Where(o => o.CourseType.Equals("SVYE"))
    .ToList();
```